# How do i make the button that's also created with the list item work? I want it to delete the current item of the array. Each item has it own button

Tags: javascript

**I tried to create an onclick event, but nothing happened**

```
    let myWork = []
const submitEl = document.getElementById("submit-el")
const clearEl = document.getElementById("clear-el")
const listEl = document.getElementById("list-el")
const textEl = document.getElementById("text-el")

submitEl.addEventListener("click", function () {
    myWork.push(textEl.value)
    renderItems()

})

clearEl.addEventListener("click", function () {
    myWork.pop()
    renderItems()
})

function renderItems() {
    let listItems = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < myWork.length; i++) {
        listItems += `<li>${myWork[i]} </li> <button>Done</button>`
    }
    listEl.innerHTML = listItems
}
```

**How do I make this button delete itself?**

Comment: Hi, is there any reason to use `listItems` at all? If you use myWork directly it could solve your issue. 

Try `myWork += `<li>${myWork[i]} </li> <button>Done</button>``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the "done" button delete its own line on click.

As a fast solution, you can write:

```
listItems += `<li>${myWork[i]} </li> <button onclick="deleteWorkByIndex(${i})>Done</button>`

function deleteWorkByIndex(index) {
    myWork.splice(index, 1); // Delete the item n°{index}
    renderItems();
}
```